# Revoke access token - Web API ( OAuth2 )

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, spring-security-oauth2

I secure Web API with OAuth2. How can i revoke access token when user logout ?

Something like : `api/issuedtoken?token="token string"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[RFC 7009](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7009) (OAuth 2.0 Token Revocation)** is a standard specification defining an API to revoke an access token or a refresh token. If your authorization server provides the revocation API, you can call it whenever you want to revoke an access token.